Linker cannot find assembly symbol
Windows 10, Visual Studio 2022 Community. x64 model. Here is the assembly file
.code
PUBLIC StubCode

StubCode PROC 
    mov rax, 4711
    ret
StubCode ENDP
end

Here is the C++ part:
extern __int64 __cdecl StubCode();

int main()
{
    __int64 n = StubCode();
    return 0;
}

The assembly file compiles without any error. Build Dependencies->Build Customization is set to masm.
The C++ file shows this:
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__int64 __cdecl StubCode(void)"
Hint on symbols that are defined and could potentially match: StubCode
I've tried __stdcall and __fastcall as well. No difference.
What is the linker missing here?

Silly question but have you passed the object file to the linker?

The asm file compiles to an .obj file, not a .lib such. Adding it to the linker I get
warning LNK4042: object specified more than once; extras ignored

Not sure if __cdecl turns off name mangling, maybe try extern "C" instead.

I just did that before I saw your comment. Its linking now.
extern "C" extern __int64 StubCode(void);

@Jester -- extern "C" doesn't "turn off" name mangling; it tells the compiler to use C mangling instead of C++. That often means attaching an _ to the beginning of the symbol. Sounds like in this case it means just use the original name, but that's certainly not required, and often not the case.

@PeteBecker yay for nitpicking. Anyway in 64 bit code underscore is no longer prepended.

@jester: Nitpicking: You forgot a comma ...

@Jester -- programmers aren't children; they don't need to be fed half-truths.

Solution:
extern "C" extern __int64 StubCode(void);
The call is a __fastcall regardless of the signature.
It means that the first four arguments are in registers, the rest on the stack. If you want to call with arguments:
.code
PUBLIC StubCode
;///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
;// Fastcall, rcx first, rdx second, r8 third, r9 fourth
;//
StubCode PROC 
    mov rax, [rsp + 40] ;Fifth 
    mov rax, [rsp + 48] ;Sixth
    mov rax, [rsp + 56] ;Seventh
    mov rax, [rsp + 64] ;... etc ...
    ret
StubCode ENDP
end

Call with
__int64 n = StubCode(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);

